# Escaping quotes in PHP

Tags: php, addslashes

How do I escape quotes in PHP when trying to query a MySQL database?

Without adding [`addslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on every value:

```
$fname = addslashes("Value's with quote''s'");
$lname = addslashes("Value's with quote''s'");
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but consider `PDO` with prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to escape *special characters* (not only quotes) **on every string value** (it's useless to escape values you're not going to enclose in quotes in a query. Those values require another treatment).

To avoid boring repetitive typing you can apply an escaping function to array items in a loop.

In case you're using MySQL and for INSERT/UPDATE queries, you can use this helper function:

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set = '';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set .= "`$field`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]) . "', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

It is used like this:

```
$id     = intval($_POST['id']);
$table  = 'users';
$fields = explode(" ","name surname lastname address zip fax phone");
$query  = "UPDATE `$table` SET ".dbSet($fields).", `date`=NOW() WHERE id=$id";
```

Also don't forget to set proper encoding using `mysql_set_charset()` as it's required for the [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() was [removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 4):

The proper way is using prepared statements, e.g. via [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community).

If you can't do that, you have to process *all* values which are passed into a database query with `mysql_real_escape_string()` - and no, doing that simply on all `$_POST` data is not an option since that would render them unusable for HTML output, etc. You could create a `$_ESC` or something similar though... but note that this variable will not be superglobal!

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() was [removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 2):

A good idea would be using PDO prepared statements as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

It will automatically escape those characters.

Comment: in fact, PDO in native mode doesn't escape anything

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a bit inaccurate. PDO in compatibility mode does the escaping, but in native mode it sends the query and the parameters to the DBMS separately. Am I right?

Comment: thanks for introducing me to pdo's. I'll definitely try it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `addslashes()` -  it is not recommended for use with escaping DB query strings because it doesn't escape everything that actually needs to be escaped; there are some characters that can still get through.

The correct solution depends on the database you're using. Assuming you're using MySQL, the correct function to use instead of `addslashes()` is `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

You probably notice that using this on every line is even more verbose than `addslashes()`, so it doesn't really answer your question.

If your fields are all separate variables (as per your example), then you're really stuck with doing that for a bunch of lines of code.

If you're using an array (eg `$_POST`), then you can do it in a loop, which will make things a lot neater - you can do things like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $sqlstrings[$key]="`".$key"` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
}
$sql = "update table ".implode(' ',$sqlstrings)." where id=".$update_id;
```

A more up-to-date method for doing SQL is to use an object model rather than manually building the queries. PHP has a number of libraries that may help: `mysqli` is an improved MySQL library, and `PDO` is a database-neutral library. Either of these would give you much better security and flexibility than building the SQL code directly. However if you already have a lot of code in place then they would represent a fairly significant overhead of code changes, so you may want to go with the `mysql_real_escape_string()` option discussed above in the short term. I do recommend investating them them though.

Comment: $_POST[] is not an array, it's operator adding new values to array

Comment: @Col: not sure what you mean there? $_POST is an array.

Comment: yes, $_POST is array and $_POST[] is operator

Comment: @Col: okay, I'm with you. Not as big a point as I thought you were making.  ;)